# Playing soundeffect on item touch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2D for iPhone, how can I play a click soundeffect *automatically* whenever the user has touched a menu item?

My idea was to change ccTouchEnded in CCMenu.m as follows:

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSAssert(state_ == kCCMenuStateTrackingTouch, 
        @"[Menu ccTouchEnded] -- invalid state");

    [selectedItem_ unselected];
    [selectedItem_ activate];

    state_ = kCCMenuStateWaiting;

    // Play a click effect whenever any menu item was touched
    [MyMusicHandler playClick];
```

}

This works and does what I want it to do. But it is "hacking the source", and I would much prefer subclassing CCMenu, instead. However, if I put that exact same method into my subclass of CCMenu it doesn't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it in one of my games:

in init (GETextMenuItem subclasses CCMenuItemLabel) :

```
confirmMenuItem_=[GETextMenuItem textMenuItemWithText:@"Buy" 
                                           dimensions:CGSizeMake(90,32) 
                                            alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter
                                                 font:@"Cochin-Bold" 
                                             fontSize:17 
                                               target:self 
                                             selector:@selector(onConfirm)];
```

and in the selector (GameEngine is a home grown singleton that provides all sorts of services available anywhere and everywhere) :

```
-(void) onConfirm{

    // immediately prevent a double click

    menu_.isTouchEnabled=NO;
    [[GameEngine sharedGameEngine].soundProvider playFxNowWithSound:@"sound_fx_menu_buy.mp3"];
    NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"quantity:%i",quantity_];
    [consumer_ menuReturnsForTag:self.menuTag withParams:params];
    [self flyOut];
}
```